# RobotFramework never release global class libraries in python

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using robot framework with python. I'm implementing a global library to be shared with all the tests. For this, I'm using `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'`. My problem is this library is never released even at the end of the program...

```
from robot.api import logger

class TestLibrary:
  ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

  def __init__ (self):
    logger.info ('Create library')

  def __del__ (self):
    logger.info ('Destroy library')
```

Looks like a bug for me, right? Does someone has a workaround to release this library at the end of the program?

Comment: What do you mean by "release"? The object is destroyed when the process exits. It _must_ , that's how processes work.

Comment: How do you instantiate the class? Are there other references to the class at program exit? You also will experience different behavior in Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: This class is instantiated by robotframework before running the test scenarios. I'm using python 2.7.8.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem -- you're needing to run code when the test is finished (X) and think that Y (the `__del__` method) is the best way to solve it, so you ask about Y. Maybe you should rephrase your question in terms of what you're really trying to accomplish, because there are solutions that don't involve `__del__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that your real problem isn't with `__del__`, but that you need to run some code when the suite is finished running. While it may seem like `__del__` is the right solution, it isn't necessarily so. 
Python doesn't guarantee that `__del__` will be run in all cases so it isn't wise to put code there that *must* be run.

Note: This isn't a fault with robot framework, it's simply how python works. Robot may very well be deleting the library object appropriately, but if the garbage collector doesn't have a chance to run before robot exits, `__del__` won't be run.

From the python documentation on `__del__`:

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects
>   that still exist when the interpreter exits.

### Running library code at the end of a test suite

If you want code to run when all suites have finished running, and you are running robot version 2.8.5 or later, you can have the library act as a listener that responds to the "close" message.

For example:

```
from robot.api import logger

class TestLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        logger.warn("Create library")

    def _close(self):
        logger.warn("Destroy library")
```

This instructs robot to call your `_close` method after all test cases have run. Within this function you can do any sort of cleanup or extra processing that you need to do.

For more information see [Test Libraries as Listeners](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-libraries-as-listeners) in the robot framework user guide.

Comment: Excellent, your code is great! Thanks a lot for your help ;)